# Concatenate columns using LEFT and RIGHT in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have two columns:
City Name and ZIP
Now, Same city names have different ZIPs
I want to generate third column which has First Letter of CIty and Last two  digits of ZIP Code.
For example My city name is SACRAMENTO and ZIP is 98532, I want to create code as S32.
I have used following formula. But it is not working

> =CONCAT(LEFT(B2,1),RIGHT(C2,2))

Where B2 contains city name and C2 contains Zip Code.

Comment: Maybe you don't have `CONCAT()`?. Use: `=LEFT(B2)&RIGHT(C2,2)`

Comment: May be the function is concatenate() , not concat()

Comment: when you say 'not working', what did you get? maybe you need to TRIM and CLEAN your city names and zip code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible that your version of Excel doesn't support Concat/concatenate function. Try to use the below formula

```
=Left(B2,1)&Right(C2,2)
```

& here does the same thing as concatenate function.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.